# Shopify - inventory_quantity deprecation notification

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am using Shopify Admin REST API for item and inventory sync and I am not sending inventory_quantity field in variants API, but I received following email from Shopify few days ago. I am also sending correct location_id when creating fulfillment and it is created successfully in Shopify.

> The location_id field is now required when creating fulfillment and
>   refund requests.
>
> Inventory_quantity and inventory_quantity_adjustment
>   can no longer be set on the product variant.

Deprecated in 2019-10 and support will be removed on July 1, 2020

I wanted to know if the email above is a generic email sent by Shopify to all developers? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I believe it is. I received one as well but it was over a month as well.

Comment: Were you sending `inventory_quantity` or `inventory_quantity_adjustment` fields to product variant API?

Comment: The APP clones the whole store to a new one, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore it if you're sure that you don't use these deprecated attributes anymore. I think they recently introduced this notification system which sends warnings to developers if they detected any deprecated calls in the past. They just alert you, they don't scan your app code so they don't know whether you fixed the issue or not. I was getting similar warnings despite that I was sure that the issue had been fixed earlier.

Anyway, to get peace of mind, go to the **Apps** area in your Shopify Partners account. The table that lists all your apps has now the **API health** column showing the status of your apps in terms of deprecated calls. You will see a warning (orange dot) if they detected any deprecated calls in the past 30 days. The warning is provided with some additional information like the last time the issue was detected and the deadline to fix it to, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhQVV.png). You can get more details about the deprecation by clicking on to the warning.

If it's a private app, just check your code again for using the deprecated attributes mentioned in the email.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check the new Inventory Level and Inventory Item endpoints in the Rest API. With a variant's inventory_item_id and a location ID, you can update inventory.

Clearly you can no longer just set a variant's inventory level. That went the way of the DODO this year.

Comment: I have already implemented inventory level endpoint. and I also mentioned in my post that `I am not sending inventory_quantity field in variants API`, but still I received that email from Shopify. Please read my question again if you did not understand my query.

Comment: The Shopify email you speak of is triggered by a simple mechanism. When your App triggers a deprecated call, you get the email. Just so you know, I did read your question, I thoroughly understand it, and I offered you advice. You are free to ignore it. You should try a search on your App code looking for the offending call. You might have overlooked one.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I am not sending inventory_quantity field in variants API which simply means I am not using it. I have already searched my app code multiple times and found no code for offending call, that is why I posted this question here.